# Div moves out of window when resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Whenever i resize the browser, the div moves out of window. I use jquery scroll to plugin for navigating through divs. But when i resize the #home div it works fine, but when i resize other divs, it gets out of window.

Please help me out, here is the [link](http://www.karthi360.com/experiments/) to the website.

Here is the code i used,

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#bg-home").backstretch("images/Bg-home3.jpg");
var images = ['1.jpg', '2.jpg','3.jpg'];
$("#container").backstretch('images/' + images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)]);
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      drag: function() {
      $(".scrolldown span").css("color","lightgreen").html("Drop");
      },
      stop: function() {
        $(".scrolldown span").css("color","white").html("Drag");
      },axis: "x",containment:"#menu",scroll: false//,grid: [ 159,0 ]
    });
$(".content,.content1").droppable({drop: function() {
        var $url = $(this);
        document.title = $url.attr('alt');
        $('html, body').scrollTo($url.attr('id'),500,"easeInOutExpo");
        //event.preventDefault();
      }});
        $("#welcome").effect("slide",3000);
        $("#welcome").click(function()
        {
            $("#welcome").animate({left: "-1000px"},"easeInOutBounce");
            $(".about_w").animate({left: "100px"},"easeInOutBounce");
            $(".about_w").delay(4000).animate({left: "-800px"});
            $("#welcome").delay(4500).animate({left: "100px"});

        });
$('#menu a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $url = $(this);
        document.title = $url.attr('alt');
        $('html, body').scrollTo($url.attr('href'),500,"easeInOutExpo");
        event.preventDefault();
    });
$("#about .text p").vertiscroll({ width:6, color:'#f07','cover': 200,'areacursor': 'pointer' });
$('.side_container').slimScroll({
    height:"88%",
    color: '#fff',
    start: $('.side_container'),
    alwaysVisible: false
});
$('#container_wrap_metro').slimScroll({
    height:"400px",
    color: '#fff',
    railVisible: false,
    alwaysVisible: false
});
$(".menu nav").click(function(){
    $url = $(this);
  $(".text p").load($url.attr('id'));
});
function loading_show()
{
$('#loading').html("<p style='color:white;'>Loading</p><br><img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
}

function loading_hide()
{
$('#loading').fadeOut();
} 
//Status
function loadData(page)
{
loading_show();
$("#container_wrap_metro").html("");
$.ajax({
      url: "load_data.php",
      type: "post",
      data: "page="+page,
      success: function(data){
            loading_hide();
           $("#container_wrap_metro").html(data);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("failure");
          $("#container_wrap_metro").html('Unable to process request!');
      }  
    }); 
}
function loads(page)
{
$.ajax({
      url: "load_10.php",
      type: "post",
      data: "page="+page,
      success: function(data){
           $(".side_container").html(data);
      },
      error:function(){
          alert("failure");
          $(".side_container").html('Unable to process request!');
      }  
    }); 
}
loads(1);
//Search
$("#result").keyup(function(){
    $(".side_container").html('<center><i>Fetching...</i></center>')
    var q = $(this).val();
    $.get("results.php?q="+q, function(data){
    if(q){
        $(".side_container").html(data);
    } 
    else {
        loads(1);
    }
});
});
});
```

Comment: For this you need responsive designs and for that you need to give widths as in "%" everywhere

Comment: But in your script you are using left:..px like that....Its creating the problem.So First thing better to give them responsively or second thing replace it with the responsive one

Comment: #welcome is just a inner div not main one. i have given main divs in %

Answer (score 1):

Try editing the following lines:

```
$("#welcome").animate({left: "-1000px"},"easeInOutBounce");
$(".about_w").animate({left: "100px"},"easeInOutBounce");
$(".about_w").delay(4000).animate({left: "-800px"});
$("#welcome").delay(4500).animate({left: "100px"});
```

And:

```
height:"400px",
```

The earlier response is right. When it comes to responsive web design, use em or % when setting the sizes. You can use 100% instead or 40 em. You can change the values until you get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

For this you need responsive designs and for that you need to give widths as in "%" everywhere But in your script you are using left:..px like that....Its creating the problem.So First thing better to give them responsively or second thing replace it with the responsive one..

Try this [**LINK**](http://codecanyon.net/item/jquery-onebyone-slider-plugin/684613?ref=pxcr)